# Generate changeLog for single sql files with liquibase

Tags: sql, migration, local, liquibase

I have a huge database with many SQL files. Is there any way to generate a changelog for single SQL files and not for the whole database? I have stored some SQL files local on my hard drive and use liquibase via command line. If there is no way to do that with local SQL files, is there a way to generate a changelog for single tables of my database?

Comment: What exactly do you need to do? To create `changeSets` based on the `sql` files? Or simple execution of `sql` files inside the `changeSet` will do? By the way, if you want to generate `changelog` for single tables, this may come in handy https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-875

Comment: I want to create changeSets based on the SQL files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is not possible. A database does not remember the SQL that was executed to get the database into a certain state. Here is a real simple example. Say that you first run some SQL to create a table with two columns 'name' and 'id'. Then you run some more sql to add a third column 'active'. The database does not remember that two separate operations were run to get into that state. When Liquibase generates a changelog for that database, it basically has to ask the database 'what is the current state of things?' and so it would have a changeset that creates the table with all three columns.

It is possible to have liquibase generate smaller changelog files, but you should probably take a step back and ask yourself why you want to do that.

Comment: Now I get it. Now I ask myself how can I generate a changeLog for that table which was generated through my local SQL files since I only found out how to run liquibase through a database with all informations like URL, username, password etc.